# [Neo]Vim can't open sourced file

Tags: neovim

So I've got the following init.vim under ~/.config/nvim/

```
source plugins.vim
```

`plugins.vim` lives in the same directory.
When I'm opening [Neo]Vim I always get

```
Error detected while processing /home/luke/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line    1:
E484: Can't open file plugins.vim
```

Does anybody know what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path for `source` command is always taken relative of the current working directory. Hence, you should specify full path instead. For example,

```
source <sfile>:h/plugins.vim
```

Another possibility is using `runtime` command that does searching along the `'runtimepath'`. E.g.

```
runtime plugins.vim
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The runtime command worked!